# jQuery selector to check if an element is animating to hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to tell if an element is either hidden or is currently in the process of hiding (via an animation)? The only way I can think to do it is to store a flag in the element's `data` when you call `show` or `hide`, but I was wondering if there was another way?

Comment: How did you end up implementing this?

Comment: Setting a flag in `data` when the animation starts, and checking for that flag again.

Comment: @nickf Ah, a solution, but not so elegant! I would love to see you get the custom selector working :)

Comment: @alex - haha, a challenge? I don't think using setTimeout as you proposed would work, since then the selection would be running asynchronously. There must be some internal "target opacity" value...

Comment: @nickf Yeah that is what I thought... I wonder if it's exposed somehow. I might ask a question here :)

Comment: @nickf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970395/in-jquery-can-you-get-the-target-opacity-of-an-element-that-is-fading

Answer (score 3):

Could you do a custom jQuery selector for it

```
 (function($) {
  var endOpacity,
      oldStep = jQuery.fx.step.opacity;

  $.fx.step.opacity = function( fx ) {
      endOpacity = fx.end;

      return oldStep(fx);
  };

$.expr[':'].hiding = function(obj){
  var $this = $(obj);

   return ($this.is(':hidden') || ($this.is(':animated') && endOpacity === 0));
};

})(jQuery);
```

[This worked for me](http://jsbin.com/ojuro3/3/edit) (it may require some more testing though).

So just add `:hiding` it will match hidden elements, and elements that are currently being animated to 0. It will now **only** match elements that are disappearing, not appearing.

Comment: this is a good start, but I think you'll hit issues when there's more than one element. See this: http://jsbin.com/ojuro3/2/edit -- click the paragraphs to make them fade out and in. Every second, hiding ones are coloured red, and non-hiding ones blue.

Comment: @nickf What about this, if you remove the element checking http://jsbin.com/ojuro3/3/edit

Answer (score 1):

You get the hidden one with `$(":hidden")` and then the animating ones with `$(":animated")` and with the `:animated` check the `.queue()` if it has the `hide` method inside.

Comment: I checked the queue with this code: `$el.slideUp('slow'); console.log($el.queue())` and all it had in it was `["in progress"]`

Comment: Well that's all the pointers I can give you - probably if you checked the jQuery source you might find a way to read of entries out of the queue object.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the element is animated like this:

```
 if( !$('.your-element').is(':animated') ) {
   // do animation...
 } else {
   return false;
 }
```