# In jQuery, can you get the "target" opacity of an element that is fading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, opacity

I'd like to somehow get the target opacity (the final value it is being animated to) of an element that is fading.

For example...

```
$('body').fadeTo(0.4); // 0.4
$('body').fadeIn(); // 1
$('body').fadeOut(); // 0
$('body').animate({ opacity: 0.7 }); // 0.7
```

Is this doable in jQuery?

### Update

For some background, see my answer here on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815439/jquery-selector-to-check-if-an-element-is-animating-to-hidden/2962650#2962650). I was trying to help out another user on SO and decided to ask this question that related to my answer.

Comment: Can't really grasp your goal here...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Maybe the question will be more understandable then.

Comment: @Zuul @Sean Vieira @Jakub Hampl I have made an update to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery uses step functions internally, you can overwrite the `jQuery.fx.step.opacity` function to read the passed `jQuery.fx` object:

```
var old = jQuery.fx.step.opacity;

jQuery.fx.step.opacity = function( fx ) {
    console.log(fx.elem);
    console.log(fx.end);

    return old(fx);
};
```

The opacity step function is called on every step of every opacity animation. You would probably want to filter the above based on `fx.elem`.

`fx.end` is the final value of the animation, `fx.now` is the current value and `fx.start` is the starting value. `fx.unit` is the unit of the values (in px, em, %, etc).

Comment: Brian, many thanks! :) I'm going to try and get this custom selector going now, I'll let you know how it all goes. May you have a great weekend!

Comment: Got it working! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815439/jquery-selector-to-check-if-an-element-is-animating-to-hidden/2962650#2962650

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there would be. There is no attributes of an object that tell where it is going, only what it is at currently. Jquery is merely animating the CSS Properties.

Failing all else...

```
var destination = 0.4;
$('body').fadeTo(destination);
//O wow. Now we know what is fading to!
```

Comment: It is animating the property with a final value set though.

Comment: See [Brian McKenna's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970395/in-jquery-can-you-get-the-target-opacity-of-an-element-that-is-fading/2971376#2971376)